# Material Design Icon to represent spots left at an event

Tags: gui-design, android, material-design

I'm looking for a material design icon to represent the amount of spots left at an event and struggling.. Any help would be verrry much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean an icon to be used with a numerical value to denote the number of spots available? Or do you just mean an icon to denote a 'button' that the user knows they click/tap on to view the number of spots left.

Comment: @Monomeeth I'd like to icon to denote the numerical value

Comment: No worries, I covered that in the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for an icon that denotes a button for users to tap on to check the number of spots left at an event, then perhaps something like these mockups I did up quickly:

[image]

**Depending on the actual purpose of the icon, I would strongly suggest adding an appropriate label.** For example, if the idea is that users can tap on the icon to view a seating plan that denotes which seats are available, than a label such as *View Seats* would be appropriate.

If the icon is not interactive and it's just to display the number of remaining seats, then you would still need to use a label such as *Seats Left* or maybe just *Seats* and adapt your icon to display a numerical value, perhaps where the cinema screen is.